# Trying to construct a regex to match tagged usernames

Tags: c#, .net, regex, facebook, string

I'm trying to build a regex (in C#) that matches tagged facebook usernames (@username1 @user.name, @user_name, etc).  I think facebook usernames can have alphanumeric, dash, period, and underscore characters.

This one matches just alphanumeric characters, but I need one that will also accept periods, dashes or underscores:

```
MatchCollection results = Regex.Matches(text, "@\\w+");
```

Any help, much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MatchCollection results = Regex.Matches(text, @"@[\w.-]+");
```

However, this will also match the domain parts of e-mail addresses (since the dot is an allowed character according to your spec). If you don't want that, you could add a negative lookbehind assertion to make sure that there is no non-space character before the `@`:

```
MatchCollection results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!\S)@[\w.-]+");
```

Comment: It turns out that this also matches usernames followed by a period (even when the period is part of the sentence and not part of the username).  For example, in this sentence "Take care @john." , it thinks the username is "john."  How could  I make this regex more intelligent so that it ignores periods at the end of the username?  My guess is that Facebook doesn't allow periods at the end of a username anyhow.

Comment: You could add a `(?<!\.)` at the end of the regex. That ensures that the last character isn't a period.

Answer (score 1):

Go with "full list" version:

```
MatchCollection results = Regex.Matches(txt, @"(?:^|(?<=\s))@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+(?=\s|$)");
```

or with short version (`\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

```
MatchCollection results = Regex.Matches(txt, @"(?:^|(?<=\s))@[\w.-]+(?=\s|$)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this

```
List<string> tagedNames=Regex.Matches(text,@"(?<=(\s|^))@[\w.-]+")
                             .Cast<Match>()
                             .Select(x=>x.Value)
                             .ToList<string>();
```